# How to test constraints on object initialization?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am writing an App for Android, and I am wanting to start writing tests for the classes I am writing. I am fairly new to writing test cases.

Right now to create a test, I use IntelliJ and use it's wizard to make a new JUnit4 test. The wizard allows me to select methods from my class to test.

But for the object I am testing, I do not want a negative number passed to the constructor.

```
class MinuteTime(private val minutes : Int) {
init {
    if (minutes < 0) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot be less than 0.")
    }
}
...
```

Where in my Test class is the best place to test these constraints? I know that to test the constraints, I just need to make sure the exception is thrown and caught, but I am unsure if I should make a new method for this, or just wedge it into one of the functions IntelliJ pre-made for me. Here is the generated test class:

```
class MinuteTimeTest {
    @Test
    fun getTimeInMinutes() {

    }

    @Test
    fun getHours() {

    }

    @Test
    fun getMinutes() {

    }

    @Test
    fun plus() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definetly recommend to wrap this into a separate test method. Its concern is simply testing the validation during initialization:

```
@Test
fun negativeNumberConstructorTest() {
    assertFailsWith(IllegalArgumentException::class){
        MinuteTime(-1)
    }
}
```

It’s using [kotlintest](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest) on top of JUnit

Comment: Thank you! Was not sure it was correct to create new functions in the test class!

Comment: You should add kotlintest, it adds such helper functions